Animated movie about kid who lost his parents in a car accident with a deer (got reunited via time travel)
I can't recall much about this movie. Most likely it was 2d. It was made in early 2000ies. I remember only few plot points:

Protag is a kid
His parents died in a car accident - they were driving, a deer jumped on the road, dad turned the car, everybody died except the kid... And the deer
Kid goes on some kind of an adventure with a newly made supernatural friend - a dragon, if my memory doesn't fail me.
No idea what happens
In the end kid bid farewell to the creature, returned back in time to the moment of car accident, warned his pops and now nobody died. 


Additional clues:
Edomin:

I do remember that part of the adventure with supernatural friends
  involves collecting some sort of magic or powerful stones or crystals.
  I specifically remember one of them being labeled as the stone of
  "Creativity" or "Imagination". The kid(protagonist) manages to earn it
  by answering a riddle given to him by an old man. The riddle is
  something along the lines of "What is the sound of one hand clapping".


Everything up until the "going back in time" section of your question matches that of Pete's Dragon, either the 2016 or the 1977 version. Are you sure that you haven't combined Pete's Dragon with another film in your head?

No, That's not it. It was animated. Anime most likely

OMG. THIS! THIS! I know exactly what movie you are talking about but I also can't remember the name. It also doesn't help that I watched it in Spanish. Any who, I do remember that part of the adventure with supernatural friends involves collecting some sort of magic or powerful stones or crystals. I specifically remember one of them being labeled as the stone of "Creativity" or "Imagination". The kid(protagonist) manages to earn it by answering a riddle given to him by an old man. The riddle is something along the lines of "What is the sound of one hand clapping". I wish I could help more. I h

Daym. I thought this is a lost cause. Thank you, friend - adding your info to the question.
